# (R) 'factor' function discards specified levels in vector

Tags: r, r-factor

First post on StackExchange, please forgive me if I format incorrectly!

If I specify the levels of a vector v in R, then call factor(v), not all of the levels will show up. I'm trying to figure out why is this the case because I need to see all levels (including "empty" levels) when I call factor for a project that I am working on.

A very simple replication of this:

```
x <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c')
levels(x) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Now if we call `levels(x)`, it will output exactly what you'd expect:

```
> levels(x)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

However, the levels change when calling `factor(x)`:

```
> factor(x)
[1] a a b b c c
Levels: a b c
```

What happened to the 'd' level that I introduced? I know there is no datapoint associated with this level, but I don't see why the level should get removed when I call 'factor'. Unfortunately, I need to be able to reference all levels when I call 'factor', so is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: Nice first question! Focused, clear, and reproducible. My one comment is: don't add too many tags. Save the RStudio tag for issues specific to RStudio, like if you have code that runs on the R command line but doesn't run in RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

When you first create `x`, its class is `character`. When you assign it `levels`, it gains a `levels` attribute, but it is still `character` class, not a `factor`:

```
x <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c')
levels(x) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
class(x)
# [1] "character"
str(x)
# chr [1:6] "a" "a" "b" "b" "c" "c"
#  - attr(*, "levels")= chr [1:4] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

When you call `factor` on an object, it is converted to `factor` class, and as the `?factor` documentation states, the default levels are

> `levels`
>
> an optional vector of the unique values (as character strings) that x might have taken. The default is the unique set of values taken by `as.character(x)`, sorted into increasing order of `x`. Note that this set can be specified as smaller than `sort(unique(x))`.

Any existing levels are not considered

```
y = factor(x)
str(y)
# Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

Even if we start with a `factor` class object, calling `factor` on it "re-factors" it with the default levels--which are only the values that are present:

```
z = factor(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'))
levels(z) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

str(z)
# Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 1 1 2 2 3 3

z = factor(z)
str(z)
# Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

As for workarounds:

- Don't call `factor` on things that are already `factor`s unless you want to change the levels. It's not clear why you need to do this. Use `is.factor()` to test if your object is a factor or not, and only call `factor()` on it if it isn't already.
- If you really have to call `factor` on a `factor` object (or even a `character` object with a `levels` attribute) and want to preserve its levels, specify its old levels in the `levels` argument, e.g., `x = factor(x, levels = levels(x))`. Note that this won't work on an object *without* a `levels` attribute, as above you probably want to use `is.factor()` to test your input and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, this completely clarifies things! I realize now why this issue was happening. I was creating a chart using `ggplots2` and used the argument `fill = factor(x)` when `x` was already a `factor` object`. Thus, certain `levels` were not showing up in my chart's legend. Removing the unneeded `factor` call solved this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Levels is an option in the `factor()` function.

```
z <- factor(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), levels=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
```

If you don't explicitly set the levels, it will create them from the actual values.